# How can I keep my Spring Cloud Contract in its own repo?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am starting to use Spring Cloud Contract for consumer driven contract development of our microservices. (Spring Boot 2.1.7, Spring Cloud Contract 2.1.2.RELEASE)

I would like to maintain a project (call it contract-repo for example) that will hold all of the contracts for our application.

The issue is that it is generating the contract verification tests in the contract-repo module, instead of the provider module.

Is there any way to get the stub generation in the contract-repo module, but the test generation into the provider module?

To my contract-repo project I am adding the following contract related dependency:

```
spring-cloud-contract-verifier
```

I also have the following plugins:

```
spring-boot-maven-plugin and

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <baseClassForTests>com.test.BaseTestClass</baseClassForTests>
        <contractDependency>
          <groupId>com.test</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-consumer</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </contractDependency>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please read the docs https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/using.html#flows-cdc-contracts-external where we describe it in details

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Lord, that is complicated. Is the maven-assembly-plugin still required if I am using Spring Boot?
What is the meaning of all of the configuration items in the scc maven plugin? The contractsPath - where is that relative too?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I have some proposed clarifications for your Spring Contracts documentation. Do you keep this in a Git repo?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc